# AWS lambda update_thing_shadow issue with rule

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, iot

I will preface by saying I am new to AWS but am required to use it to set up a MQTT broker for class. The problem may stem that I am just unfamiliar with how it should be used but whenever I update the shadow of my thing "TestMichael" using a lambda function the rule should send an sms notification if the temperature is out of range but it doesn't. When I publish it under the test the notification works but not when the lambda function changes it. Does anybody know why that is?

**TLDR: Updating the thing's shadow with a lambda function won't activate the rule I created. Why is this?**

Heres the relevant lambda function and rule query:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
temp = 74 #text should be sent if > 70
client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')

#Code portion for changing the state
data = {"state" : { "reported" : { "Temperature" : temp , "Moisture" : moist, "Light" : light, "Conductivity" : conduct}}}
mypayload = json.dumps(data)
response = client.update_thing_shadow(
    thingName = 'TestMichael', 
    payload = mypayload
)
```

Here is the SQL query used in my rule:

```
SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/TestMichael/shadow/update' WHERE Temperature > 70
```

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I check by using the test functionality in AWS IoT. You can listen to the '$aws/things/TestMichael/shadow/update' topic and see if it is getting data published when the lambda updates the shadow.